# Separate row created for data that can be included in same row with same id

Tags: sql, postgresql, pentaho, kettle

I have this table that consists of sales data. There are two workers or sorts (in kettle/pentaho in .ktr file) which enters the data into the same table: 1) sales and 2)routes. They will look for the same delivery_id so that means if data from sales and routes have the same delivery_id, it'll get updated in the same row. But I noticed that sometimes a new separate row is created for the routes data.
Example:

```
delivery_id  | order_id | route_name   | sales_id |
---------------------------------------------------
del1         |          |      test    | 1234
del1         | order1   |              |
---------------------------------------------------
```

I was wondering what is causing this since they don't have any different data in the same columns and it should produce one row instead of two. And how can I fix this if possible?

I tried running the worker to enter the data again but seems like it's the same result. Not sure how to handle this. Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: It is presumably caused because the application successfully inserts two rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff does that mean that sometimes this will happen regardless of having the same id? how can i stop it from happening and how to fix the above? Thanks

Comment: I have no idea.  The point is that you get two rows because something inserts two rows.  You haven't provided enough information for further explanation.

Comment: As Gordon says, probably you are getting two rows because something in your data or your logic generate it. First I would look why is this happening, and if it's correct given your datasource and your logic, then to unify it, given that your example is the kind of data you are getting, I would add a Group by operator, grouping by delivery_id, and getting the max value of order_id, route_name and sales_id. Beware, if you can get two rows with different values both in order_id, route_name or sales_id and the same delivery_id, then this solution is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. appreciate it very much. It seems that when the routes worker ran, there's no sales data yet hence why a separate row is created. Running the worker from the date of the missing data works as now the data is synced.